# Text doesn't show when hover over

Tags: css, html, hover

I am creating a website using wordpress and I've added some additional css also. There is a image and there is some text underneath it; when I hover over the image the image highlights but the text doesn't show up.

What I want is the text to appear with some background color when hover over it.

Comment: what code have you tried? edit the question and post it

Comment: Jaymal, please read [ask] and modify your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

However your question is not clear enough to answer, may be its due to z-index values of image & text.